# Enabling asp.net HTTP Post for webservice?

Tags: asp.net, web-services

On our local dev server, the web services we created list both SOAP and HTTP Post options.  However on the production server only SOAP is being listed.

Is there some explicit setting that needs to be made for remote servers to enable HTTP Post?  I had thought it was on by default unless you explicitly turned it off.

This is ASP.NET 2.0 framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302435.aspx

```
> The <protocols> element defines the
> protocols that Web services support.
> By default, HttpPost and HttpGet are
> disabled on .NET Framework versions
> 1.1 and 2.0 as follows:
>     <webServices>
>       <protocols>
>         <add name="HttpSoap1.2"/>
>         <add name="HttpSoap"/>
>         <!-- <add name="HttpPost"/> -->
>         <!-- <add name="HttpGet"/> -->
>         <add name="HttpPostLocalhost"/>
>         <add name="Documentation"/>
>       </protocols>
>     </webServices>
```